# ¿Como reescribir una consulta SQL para hacerla mas legible y optimizar plan de ejecución?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día.

Tengo la siguiente tabla sobre la cual construí una consulta (la colocare al final de la pregunta)

```
create table  ConsultaPruebasCargaViral
(

      Id_Prueba_Solicitada int, 
      Id_Pac int,
      Fecha_Solicitud date, 
      EsCVBasal smallint, 
      Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud smallint, 
      Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud varchar (50), 
      Carga_Viral_VIH int   
)
```

con los siguientes datos (solo es una muestra de los datos)

```
introducir el código aquí   insert into  ConsultaPruebasCargaViral (Id_Prueba_Solicitada, Id_Pac, Fecha_Solicitud, EsCVBasal, Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, Carga_Viral_VIH)
select Id_Pac, Id_Prueba_Solicitada, Fecha_Solicitud, EsCVBasal, Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, Carga_Viral_VIH
from
(
              select    22953   Id_Pac, 98776   Id_Prueba_Solicitada, '2018-12-17' Fecha_Solicitud  ,   1   EsCVBasal,  1  Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud,  'Inicio, Diagnóstico reciente de VIH' Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud,  116126  Carga_Viral_VIH
    union all select    22953         , 100696                      , '2018-12-27'                  ,   2            ,  4                            ,  'Seguimiento/Control Tratamiento    '                             , 387     
    union all select    22953         , 108438                      , '2019-02-05'                  ,   2            ,  4                            ,  'Seguimiento/Control Tratamiento    '                             , 527     
    union all select    22953         , 114489                      , '2019-03-06'                  ,   2            ,  4                            ,  'Seguimiento/Control Tratamiento    '                             , 246     
)t
```

Y necesito consultar con base a este campo : Id_Prueba_Solicitada. La consulta debe devolverme el registro con un Id_Prueba_Solicitada especifico y DOS (únicamente dos ) registros previos a este, pero debe retornar NULL si estos no existen.

Por ejemplo : si consulto con este id (Id_Prueba_Solicitada = 114489) la consulta me devolverá la siguiente lista :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, si consulto con este Id ( Id_Prueba_Solicitada = 100696). la lista resultante devuelve NULL en la ultima fila:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y NULL en los dos previos si consulto por el primer registro (Id_Prueba_Solicitada = 98776)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el script que construí para obtener estos valores:

```js
WITH ConsultaResultadosPaciente as
(
  select Id_Pac, Id_Prueba_Solicitada, Fecha_Solicitud, EsCVBasal, Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, Carga_Viral_VIH
  from ConsultaPruebasCargaViral where Id_Pac = 22953

),CargaViralEvaluada AS (   
   select top 1 Orden,  Id_Pac, Id_Prueba_Solicitada, Fecha_Solicitud, EsCVBasal, Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, Carga_Viral_VIH
   from
   (
     select '0' Orden, NULL Id_Pac, NULL Id_Prueba_Solicitada, NULL Fecha_Solicitud, NULL EsCVBasal, NULL Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, NULL Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, NULL Carga_Viral_VIH    
    union
     select '1' Orden,  Id_Pac, Id_Prueba_Solicitada, Fecha_Solicitud, EsCVBasal, Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, Carga_Viral_VIH
     from ConsultaResultadosPaciente
     where  Id_Prueba_Solicitada = 98776       
   )Sorter order by Sorter.Orden desc 
), CargaViralPrevia1 as
(
   select top 1 cvp.Orden,  cvp.Id_Pac, cvp.Id_Prueba_Solicitada, cvp.Fecha_Solicitud, cvp.EsCVBasal, cvp.Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, cvp.Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, cvp.Carga_Viral_VIH
   from (   
     select '0' Orden, NULL Id_Pac, NULL Id_Prueba_Solicitada, NULL Fecha_Solicitud, NULL EsCVBasal, NULL Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, NULL Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, NULL Carga_Viral_VIH    
    union
     select '1' Orden,  crp.Id_Pac, crp.Id_Prueba_Solicitada, crp.Fecha_Solicitud, crp.EsCVBasal, crp.Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, crp.Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, crp.Carga_Viral_VIH
     from(
      select crp.Id_Pac, crp.Id_Prueba_Solicitada, crp.Fecha_Solicitud, crp.EsCVBasal, crp.Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, crp.Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, crp.Carga_Viral_VIH,
          ROW_NUMBER () OVER (order by crp.Fecha_Solicitud desc) NumFecha
      from ConsultaResultadosPaciente crp
      left join CargaViralEvaluada cve
      on   crp.Id_Pac =   cve.Id_Pac where crp.Fecha_Solicitud < cve.Fecha_Solicitud
     )crp     
     where crp. NumFecha = 1
   ) cvp order by cvp.Orden desc                  
), CargaViralPrevia2 as
(
   select top 1 cvp.Orden,  cvp.Id_Pac, cvp.Id_Prueba_Solicitada, cvp.Fecha_Solicitud, cvp.EsCVBasal, cvp.Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, cvp.Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, cvp.Carga_Viral_VIH
   from (   
     select '0' Orden, NULL Id_Pac, NULL Id_Prueba_Solicitada, NULL Fecha_Solicitud, NULL EsCVBasal, NULL Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, NULL Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, NULL Carga_Viral_VIH    
    union
     select '1' Orden,  cvp.Id_Pac, cvp.Id_Prueba_Solicitada, cvp.Fecha_Solicitud, cvp.EsCVBasal, cvp.Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, cvp.Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, cvp.Carga_Viral_VIH
     from(
      select crp.Id_Pac, crp.Id_Prueba_Solicitada, crp.Fecha_Solicitud, crp.EsCVBasal, crp.Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, crp.Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, crp.Carga_Viral_VIH,
          ROW_NUMBER () OVER (order by crp.Fecha_Solicitud desc) NumFecha
      from ConsultaResultadosPaciente crp
      left join CargaViralPrevia1 cve
      on   crp.Id_Pac =   cve.Id_Pac where crp.Fecha_Solicitud < cve.Fecha_Solicitud
     )cvp     
     where cvp. NumFecha = 1           
   ) cvp order by cvp.Orden desc           
)
select * from CargaViralEvaluada
union all
select * from CargaViralPrevia1
union all
select * from CargaViralPrevia2
```

El script funciona bien, hace lo que necesito, pero me gustaría poder reescribirlo para hacerlo mas eficiente en dos sentidos:

1. Que la lógica permita que el script sea mas legible puesto que el contexto donde se utiliza hace elegible mi actual versión
2. Que genere un plan de ejecución mas eficiente.

Agradezco de antemano el tiempo que puedan tomarse.

Comment: Tienes gran parte identica. Crea una funcion con parametros y sustituyes partes iguales por la funcion. Lo poco que cambia en función, lo pasas por parametro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí dejo una forma de hacerlo. Primero limitamos por fecha y luego definimos la cantidad de resultados disponibles usando el RIGHT JOIN hacia una tabla de números. Estoy usando ANY para prevenir errores en caso de que el valor de Id_Prueba_Solicitada no sea único.

```
DECLARE @Id_Pac int = 22953,
        @Id_Prueba_Solicitada int = 100696;

WITH ConsultaResultadosPaciente
     AS (SELECT Id_Pac, 
                Id_Prueba_Solicitada, 
                Fecha_Solicitud, 
                EsCVBasal, 
                Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, 
                Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud, 
                Carga_Viral_VIH,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Fecha_Solicitud DESC) rn
         FROM   ConsultaPruebasCargaViral
         WHERE  Id_Pac = @Id_Pac
         AND    Fecha_Solicitud <= ANY(SELECT Fecha_Solicitud 
                                       FROM ConsultaPruebasCargaViral 
                                       WHERE Id_Prueba_Solicitada = @Id_Prueba_Solicitada))
SELECT crp.Id_Pac,
        crp.Id_Prueba_Solicitada,
        crp.Fecha_Solicitud,
        crp.EsCVBasal,
        crp.Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud,
        crp.Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud,
        crp.Carga_Viral_VIH
FROM ConsultaResultadosPaciente crp
RIGHT JOIN( VALUES(1),(2),(3))x(n) ON crp.rn = x.n;
```

**NOTA:**

Tu consulta original es más eficiente que esta si existe un índice clustered en la columna Id_Pac.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_ConsultaPruebasCargaViral] 
ON [dbo].[ConsultaPruebasCargaViral] ([Id_Pac]);
```

La diferencia es mínima y los resultados son básicamente inmediatos en un millón de filas (no se detectan con `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`).

Aparte del índice clustered, mi consulta también se beneficia del siguiente índice:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ConsultaPruebasCargaViral_Id_Prueba_Solicitada] 
ON [dbo].[ConsultaPruebasCargaViral] (Id_Prueba_Solicitada)
INCLUDE ([Fecha_Solicitud]);
```

Dejo además el código para crear una prueba con un millón de filas. Puede tardar un poco en cargarse.

```
CREATE TABLE ConsultaPruebasCargaViral
(
             Id_Prueba_Solicitada        INT, 
             Id_Pac                      INT, 
             Fecha_Solicitud             DATE, 
             EsCVBasal                   SMALLINT, 
             Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud  SMALLINT, 
             Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud VARCHAR(50), 
             Carga_Viral_VIH             INT
);

INSERT INTO ConsultaPruebasCargaViral
    (Id_Pac, 
     Id_Prueba_Solicitada, 
     Fecha_Solicitud, 
     Carga_Viral_VIH
    )
SELECT TOP(1000000)
       a.,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()),
       DATEADD( DD, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10000, '2016'),
       ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10000
FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id_Pac ORDER BY Fecha_Solicitud) rn
    FROM ConsultaPruebasCargaViral
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 'Inicio, Diagnóstico reciente de VIH'  ELSE 'Seguimiento/Control Tratamiento' END,
    Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 4 END,
    EsCVBasal = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede simplificar mucho, desde el punto de vista que los datos vienen de una sola tabla.

Te explico mi enfoque:

- Primero, en el CTE `Ordenacion` establezco un *número de fila* para cada registro, por paciente, fecha de solicitud e `Id_prueba_solicitada`, solo en caso que haya varias solicitudes en la misma fecha.
- Luego, en el CTE `Seleccion` me quedo con los primeros 3 registros en orden descendente por el *número de fila*, siempre que sean menores o iguales al número de fila del registro buscado.
- A esta selección, por si hiciera falta, le uno dos registros que tienen `null` en todos los campos, excepto que el número de fila es negativo, para poder ordenarlos al final.
- Finalmente, selecciono los primeros tres registros del CTE `Seleccion`.

Creo que la consulta es mucho más legible y fácil de mantener. Supongo también que el plan de ejecución será más óptimo, por el simple hecho de darle menos vueltas a los datos.

El código luce así:

```
declare @id_Pac int = 22953;
declare @Id_Prueba_Solicitada int = 100696;

WITH 
Ordenacion as (
select   ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id_pac order by fecha_solicitud, Id_Prueba_Solicitada) NumRegistro
       , a.*
  from ConsultaPruebasCargaViral a
)
,
Seleccion as (
select top 3 a.*
  from Ordenacion a
 where a.NumRegistro <= (select NumRegistro
  from Ordenacion a
 where a.Id_Pac = @id_Pac
   and a.Id_Prueba_Solicitada = @Id_Prueba_Solicitada)
 order by a.NumRegistro desc
union all select -1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
union all select -2, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
union all select -3, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
)
select top 3 
         Id_Pac
       , Id_Prueba_Solicitada
       , Fecha_Solicitud
       , EsCVBasal
       , Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud
       , Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud
       , Carga_Viral_VIH
  from Seleccion a
 order by NumRegistro desc;
```

Los resultados obtenidos son:

```
declare @id_Pac int = 22953;
declare @Id_Prueba_Solicitada int = 100696;

Id_Pac      Id_Prueba_Solicitada Fecha_Solicitud EsCVBasal   Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud         Carga_Viral_VIH
----------- -------------------- --------------- ----------- -------------------------- ----------------------------------- ---------------
22953       100696               2018-12-27      2           4                          Seguimiento/Control Tratamiento     387
22953       98776                2018-12-17      1           1                          Inicio, Diagnóstico reciente de VIH 116126
NULL        NULL                 NULL            NULL        NULL                       NULL                                NULL

(3 rows affected)


declare @id_Pac int = 22953;
declare @Id_Prueba_Solicitada int = 98776;

Id_Pac      Id_Prueba_Solicitada Fecha_Solicitud EsCVBasal   Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud         Carga_Viral_VIH
----------- -------------------- --------------- ----------- -------------------------- ----------------------------------- ---------------
22953       98776                2018-12-17      1           1                          Inicio, Diagnóstico reciente de VIH 116126
NULL        NULL                 NULL            NULL        NULL                       NULL                                NULL
NULL        NULL                 NULL            NULL        NULL                       NULL                                NULL

(3 rows affected)

declare @id_Pac int = 22953;
declare @Id_Prueba_Solicitada int = 114489;

Id_Pac      Id_Prueba_Solicitada Fecha_Solicitud EsCVBasal   Id_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud Nom_Tipo_Paciente_Solicitud         Carga_Viral_VIH
----------- -------------------- --------------- ----------- -------------------------- ----------------------------------- ---------------
22953       114489               2019-03-06      2           4                          Seguimiento/Control Tratamiento     246
22953       108438               2019-02-05      2           4                          Seguimiento/Control Tratamiento     527
22953       100696               2018-12-27      2           4                          Seguimiento/Control Tratamiento     387

(3 rows affected)
```

Comment: Creando un escenario de prueba más grande, se pueden detectar 2 cosas. La consulta será más lenta porque estás ordenando toda la tabla con el ROW_NUMBER en vez de sólo el conjunto necesario. Y además el resultado no coincide porque no limitas el resultado a un determinado Id_Pac.

Comment: 1. El resultado es correcto, `Id_Pac` se toma en cuenta en el `where` del CTE `seleccion`. Dado que esta vista se construye generalmente en memoria y el motor va a trasladar el filtro del paciente a la primera consulta, dudo que el desempeño sea pobre, pero podríamos hacer una prueba con unos cuantos miles de registros a ver si lo es.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta para agregar datos de prueba con un millón de filas. Con esos probé las 3 opciones y fue cuando descubrí los problemas con tu solución y los índices que se pueden aplicar.